# Is it possible to create custom groups in the creative inventory?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I'm experimenting with Minecraft Bedrock addons. Currently I'm working with adding custom blocks. In the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/reference/content/blockreference/examples/blockcomponents/minecraftblock_creative_category#groups), they show you can add your block to groups in the creative inventory. Is there any way to make a new group (to group all of my custom blocks)?