# What group name should I use to make a custom block show up in the Creative Inventory in the same category as gem/metal blocks?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons, minecraft-behavior-packs

Using a resource and behavior pack, I made an Echo Block which is craftable from 9 Echo Shards, and so I want it to appear in the same part of the Creative Mode inventory menu as the other blocks which are made from 9 of a special material (e.g. metals or gems). Ideally, I'd like it to appear right after the Block of Raw Gold, but anywhere in that general vicinity is fine. Right now, I tried setting the category and group (inside `echo_block.json` in the "blocks" folder within the behavior pack) as follows:

```
{ 
    "format_version": "1.20.20", 
    "minecraft:block": { 
        "description": { 
            "identifier": "addtns:echo_block",
            "menu_category": {
                "category": "construction",
                "group": "itemGroup.name.copper"
            }
        }, 
        "components": { 
            "minecraft:light_emission": 7,
            "minecraft:destructible_by_mining": {
                 "seconds_to_destroy": 5
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

(I tried using `itemGroup.name.copper` because looking at this [list of group names](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/documentation/creative-categories.html#for-blocks), that was the most likely looking candidate out of the given options.)

**Result: The custom block shows up as the very last thing in the menu - not anywhere near the copper blocks or the other metal & gem blocks.** It *is* correctly tagged with the category name "Construction," though.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: inventory screenshot]

**So, it looks like the line `"group": "itemGroup.name.copper"` is not doing anything at all.** Why is this, and how can I fix it? There seems to be a similar question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/399212/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-groups-in-the-creative-inventory), but it is a year old and has no answers.

Everything else about the block (texture, animation, mining and the crafting recipe) works as intended, just not the menu positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
Before, I had been looking at the Search tab (with **all** possible blocks and items) instead of a more specific tab within the Creative Inventory. When viewing the "Construction" *tab*, the custom block ***does*** actually show up in the expandable group under the copper block.

Screenshot of "Construction" tab:
[image: construction materials tab picture showing block in correct place]

However, **it still seems strange that in the Search tab, the block is placed in the last slot and not next to the copper blocks**. It doesn't seem likely that there is a way to "fix" this, though, and it is a minor issue.

Comment: Thanks - I had *considered* posting this as an answer instead of an edit, but wasn't sure it really constituted a solution.  Since the item group **is** working within the relevant page, it doesn't seem likely that there is an actual fix for the "All" tab, so I accepted your answer.